# integral sign size problem with lualatex and libertine

Tags: luatex, libertine, newtxmath

I just came across the following weird bug. In this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
     These are the same \(\int \displaystyle\int\); but these aren't \(\sum \displaystyle\sum\)
\end{document}
```

the size of the two integral signs turns out the same when the code is compiled with `lualatex`. On the other hand, the sums do have the correct size.

Whenever the code is compiled with `xelatex` everything goes well and the sizes are the expected sizes.

The order of the inclusion of the packages doesn't matter.
If one removes either of the packages the problem is not reproduced.

What's going on?

Comment: looks ok. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: strange indeed, just tried in Overleaf and compiles just fine. So my system must not be up-to-date. How do I check that?

Comment: by looking in the log-file.

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for in the log-file?

Comment: dates would be a good start, compare it then with the overleaf log-file.